# Is it considered a good practice to hardcode package versions in something as high-level as a Dockerfile?

Tags: architecture, programming-practices, builds, docker

We had an application break in production during a deployment because a load-balancer package in our top-level Dockerfile had pulled its latest version, which happened to have a new API. Our app broke during a time when most of our developers were out of the office, so I and another dev had to scramble into the night trying to fix the error. Because our latest build had many new features, it took us a few hours to discover that it was a version change in the Dockerfile that had caused the entire application to break.

Since we use CI/CD practices, I thought perhaps it might be a good idea to hardcode the version of this package in the Dockerfile, since it is such a high-level component of the application. Which I did.

My reasoning is that in the future, when staff are "hands on deck" and available to fix any issues, we can upgrade the top-level packages in our Dockerfile (there aren't many of them), carefully checking for versions which break the app.

Is this considered good or bad practice? Why?

Comment: At the point of release it should be hard-coded. I would even go so far as to require that all package dependencies are pushed into a "deployment" docker repo. That way exact binaries are guaranteed, and you avoid replicating the NPM pad left fiasco.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be asking the wrong question. Good practice or bad practice for a Dockerfile, because they have so many different applications, depends on what exactly you do with them.

However, if your real question is: How should I deal with this potential for breakage? The answer is, only build your docker image once, as the very first step of your pipeline. Then you do your testing with that image, your staging deployment with that image, and finally your production deployment with it.

Given the right kind of tests, then, you will never have a different API to deal with in production than you had in staging or testing.